# Uefi Protocol : error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Print3Hello’

Tags: c, uefi

I am trying to write a simple UEFI protocol based on the Print2 Protocol.

Here is the entire error of the compilation :

```
Building ... /home/qwn/src/edk2/Print3/Print3.inf [X64]
"gcc" -g -fshort-wchar -fno-builtin -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Werror -Wno-array-bounds -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -include AutoGen.h -fno-common -DSTRING_ARRAY_NAME=Print3Strings -m64 -fno-stack-protector "-DEFIAPI=__attribute__((ms_abi))" -maccumulate-outgoing-args -mno-red-zone -Wno-address -mcmodel=small -fpie -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -Wno-address -flto -DUSING_LTO -Os -D DISABLE_NEW_DEPRECATED_INTERFACES -c -o /home/qwn/src/edk2/Build/MdeModule/DEBUG_GCC5/X64/Print3/Print3/OUTPUT/./Print3.obj -I/home/qwn/src/edk2/Print3 -I/home/qwn/src/edk2/Build/MdeModule/DEBUG_GCC5/X64/Print3/Print3/DEBUG -I/home/qwn/src/edk2/MdePkg -I/home/qwn/src/edk2/MdePkg/Include -I/home/qwn/src/edk2/MdePkg/Include/X64 -I/home/qwn/src/edk2/MdeModulePkg -I/home/qwn/src/edk2/MdeModulePkg/Include /home/qwn/src/edk2/Print3/Print3.c
/home/qwn/src/edk2/Print3/Print3.c:5:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Print3Hello’
 Print3Hello()
 ^

/home/qwn/src/edk2/Print3/Print3.c:12:3: error: ‘Print3Hello’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 Print3Hello
 ^

/home/qwn/src/edk2/Print3/Print3.c:20:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘Print3Entry’
 Print3Entry(
 ^

GNUmakefile:411: recipe for target '/home/qwn/src/edk2/Build/MdeModule/DEBUG_GCC5/X64/Print3/Print3/OUTPUT/Print3.obj' failed
make: *** [/home/qwn/src/edk2/Build/MdeModule/DEBUG_GCC5/X64/Print3/Print3/OUTPUT/Print3.obj] Error 1
```

This is the main .c file

```
#include "Print3.h"

EFI_STATUS
EFIAPT
Print3Hello()
{
  Print(L"Hello, self defined print3 protocol \n");
  return EFI_SUCCESS; 
}

EFI_PRINT3_PROTOCOL myPrint3Protocol = {
  Print3Hello
};

//Entry function for the driver, here we install the protocol  
EFI_HANDLE print3ProtocolHandle = NULL;

EFI_STATUS
EFIAPT
Print3Entry(
  EFI_HANDLE       imageHandle,
  EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *systemTable
)
{
  EFI_STATUS status;

  status = gBS->InstallProtocolInterface(&print3ProtocolHandle,
                                         &gEfiPrint3ProtocolGuid,
                                         &myPrint3Protocol,
                                         NULL
                                         );
  ASSERT_EFI_ERROR (status);
  reutrn status;
}
```

Here is the .h

```
#ifndef _PRINT3_H_
#define _PRINT3_H_

#include <Uefi.h>
#include <Library/UefiLib.h>
#include <Library/UefiDriverEntryPoint.h>
#include <Library/UefiBootServicesTableLib.h>


//Guid for the print 3 protocol.
#define EFI_PRINT3_PROTOCOL_GUI \
  { 0x3b777e4b, 0x93b1, 0x4985, { 0xb0, 0x55, 0x52, 0x55, 0x1b, 0x54, 0xcc, 0xcc }}

typedef
EFI_STATUS
(EFIAPI *EFI_PRINT_STRING)();


typedef struct _EFI_PRINT3_PROTOCOL {
  EFI_PRINT_STRING efiPrintHello;
}EFI_PRINT3_PROTOCOL;

extern EFI_GUID gEfiPrint3ProtocolGuid;
#endif
```

And finally here is the inf

```
[Defines]
 INF_VERSION                    = 1.25
 BASE_NAME                      = Print3
 FILE_GUID                      = f4df2436-242b-4e13-ae42-50c30118eff2
 MODULE_TYPE                    = UEFI_DRIVER
 VERSION_STRING                 = 1.0
 ENTRY_POINT                    = Print3Entry


[Sources]
        Print3.h
        Print3.c

[Packages]
        MdePkg/MdePkg.dec
        MdeModulePkg/MdeModulePkg.dec

[LibraryClasses]
        UefiLib
        UefiDriverEntryPoint
        UefiBootServicesTableLib

[Guids]

[Ppis]

[Protocols]
        gEfiPrint3ProtocolGuid

[FeaturePcd]

[Pcd]
```

The GUID for the Print3 is defined in MdeModule/MdeModule.dec

```
## Print3/Print3.h
gEfiPrint3ProtocolGuid = { 0x3b777e4b, 0x93b1, 0x4985, { 0xb0, 0x55, 0x52, 0x55, 0x1b, 0x54, 0xcc, 0xcc }}
```

I have followed the Print2 Protocol implemented in the UEFi library. The inf file is from the print2.inf except for the GUID which I generated and I changed the variable names.

The headers have been used in the Print2 protocol. It must be something very silly that Iam missing

Comment: `EFI_STATUS` or `EFIAPT` are undefined. ... Wait, did you mean `EFIAPI` instead of `EFIAPT`?

Comment: `reutrn` is also misspelled.

Comment: @melpomene Tsk! taht was very stupid of me. If you want to write an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you may find another error later, but the ones you are getting look like they are because the macro EFIAPT is not defined. I think you mean EFIAPI.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I didn't see that melpomene had pointed out this error and another one in the comments before I posted this.